# Access to controls from another thread

Tags: c#

I dont can get access to checkBox control, how I can do it?
I have code what must checking CheckBox properties of checked into another thread

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(fbd);
static void fbd()
        {
            if (chb1.Checked == true)
            {

            }
        }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thread1.Start();
        }
```

If using this method then compiler showing error.
If add links thread starting, but process doesnt work

```
Form1 form = new Form();
if (form.chb1.Checked == true)
            {
                \\действие
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(form.name);
```

How I can get access to controls and variables from another thread. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  If you need to share data across threads, use a proper data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
    private void fbd()
    {
        if (chb1.Checked == true)
        {

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fbd));
        thread1.Start();
    }
```